# Save reference to a function with parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function at several places within my app. This function takes several parameters whose values might change. To avoid re-typing, I want to save a reference to this function so that I can simply call this referred function everywhere. Here is the simplified code:

```
const func1 = (a,b,c) => a + b + c; 
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
const func2 = func1.bind(this, a, b, c);
func2();
//prints 6
c = 6;
func2();
//still prints 6!
```

How can I ge `func1` to be executed with updated values of `a`, `b` and `c` by calling `func2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrow function:

```js
const func1 = (a,b,c) => a + b + c; 
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
const func2 = () => func1(a, b, c);
console.log(func2());
c = 6;
console.log(func2());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function to an array of `[a, b, c]` instead, and then change the property at index 2:

```
const func1 = (a,b,c) => a + b + c; 
const params = [1, 2, 3];
const func2 = () => func1(...params);
func2();
params[2] = 6;
func2();
```

If you only change `c`, you could consider binding the function to `a` and `b`, and then passing the changing `c`:

```
const func1 = (a,b,c) => a + b + c; 
const params = [1, 2];
const func2 = (c) => func1(...params, c);
func2(3);
func2(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use params from scope where you declare your function, just skip those params in function signature

```js
const f = () => a + b + c;
let a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
console.log(f());
c = 6;
console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `const func2 = func1.bind(this, a, b, c);`

You can use this function(arrow): `const func2 = () => func1(a, b, c);`